# angular js The ng-model name looks like 'choice.gorntu'. I want pz1, pz2 etc. to be written in ng-model part

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jovw.png)

The ng-model name looks like 'choice.gorntu'. I want pz1, pz2 etc. to be written in ng-model part. I did not get it. My English is not very good.

html

```
        <div ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <input type="text" -ng-model='choice.gorntu' name="{{choice.isim}}" >


        </div>
        <input type="button" value='add'  ng-click="addNewchoice()">
```

css

```
 var benimapp =angular.module("myapp",[]);
    benimapp.controller("control",function($scope){
         $scope.choices = [{id: 'txt1',isim:'monday1',gorntu:'pz1'},{id: 

'txt2',isim:'monday2',gorntu:'pz2'}];
  $scope.addNewchoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'txt'+newItemNo ,isim:'monday'+newItemNo, gorntu:'pz'+newItemNo});
  }; 
  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="control">

<div ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <input type="text" ng-model='choice.gorntu' name="{{choice.isim}}" >


        </div>
        <input type="button" value='add'  ng-click="addNewchoice()">

</div>

<script>
var benimapp =angular.module("myapp",[]);
    benimapp.controller("control",function($scope){
         $scope.choices = [{id: 'txt1',isim:'monday1',gorntu:'pz1'},{id: 

'txt2',isim:'monday2',gorntu:'pz2'}];
  $scope.addNewchoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'txt'+newItemNo ,isim:'monday'+newItemNo, gorntu:'pz'+newItemNo});
  }; 
  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you click on add button an <input type="text" /> added with text pz1,  pz2, pz3, .....pzn. Am i right @fatih yilmaz

Comment: It is not what I want . <input ng-model='pz1' 
In the form of

Comment: When you click on add button an